# Bind int property with StringFormat in BorderThinkness

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, string-formatting

I have a template with a own property BorderWidth:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderWidth", typeof(int), typeof(ProjectOverviewSensor), new PropertyMetadata(1));
```

Now i want to bind this property to BorderThickness with StringFormat in my template for create a border to specific sides. But it is ever 1 in all four sides.

```
<Border BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, StringFormat='{}{0},0,{0},0'}"></Border>
```

How i can bind the property only to the sides of border control, that i want? Are there a alternative to stringformat?

Comment: Is changing the type of `BorderWidth` to a `Thickness` an alternative?

Comment: A have a template with several borders with uniform border width, but all borders receive the borderwidth in different sides. Create for every border a own property is in my opinion very bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i created a extended converter and I want him not to hide from you.

```
public class CustomThicknessConverter : IValueConverter
{
    protected readonly char SplitChar = ',';
    protected readonly char ReplaceAt = '#';

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a thickness with custom format(for example #,2,#,5).
    /// </summary>
    /// Number for default width.
    /// # for given border width.
    /// ; for split the chars.
    /// For example '#,0,#,0' with 1 as value return a new thickness 
    /// with Left = 1, Top = 0, Right = 1, Bottom = 0.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            return value;

        var borderWidth = value as double?;
        var format = parameter.ToString().Split(SplitChar); 

        if(format.Length == 1)
            return new Thickness(GetValue(borderWidth, format[0]));

        else if(format.Length == 2)
        {
            return new Thickness()
            {
                Left    = GetValue(borderWidth, format[0]),
                Top     = GetValue(borderWidth, format[1]),
                Right   = GetValue(borderWidth, format[0]),
                Bottom  = GetValue(borderWidth, format[1])
            };
        }

        else if(format.Length == 4)
        {
            return new Thickness()
            {
                Left    = GetValue(borderWidth, format[0]),
                Top     = GetValue(borderWidth, format[1]),
                Right   = GetValue(borderWidth, format[2]),
                Bottom  = GetValue(borderWidth, format[3])
            };
        }

        return new Thickness(0);
    }

    private double GetValue(double? value, string format)
    {
        if(format.FirstOrDefault() == ReplaceAt) return value ?? 0;

        double result;
        return (Double.TryParse(format, out result)) ? result : 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<local:CustomThicknessConverter x:Key="CustomThicknessConverter" />    
<Border BorderThickness="{Binding BorderWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource CustomThicknessConverter}, ConverterParameter='0,#,0,#'}">

</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Binding.StringFormat` only works on properties of type `System.String`.

It is a different story with a string written in XAML, since here, the XAML parser converts the string to a thickness value during parsing.

To do what you want you will need a converter on the binding:

```
class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            return value;
        return new Thickness((int)value,0, (int)value, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Thickness)value).Left;
    }   
}
```

And use like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <MyConverter x:Key="ToThickness"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Border BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource ToThickness}"></Border>
```